# Python Error in __init__.py import modules

Tags: python-3.x, python-import, importerror

## 1. What I'm trying to do

I searched/read several posts on this forum, but no solution worked for me. This minor error is still holding me back.

I am trying the access some classes from a parent file and keep getting an `ImportError`.

## 2. My Setup

`/website`

- `__init__.py` => `from .client import Client`
- `main.py` => `from client import Client`

  `/client`

  - `__init__.py` => `from client import Client`
  - `client.py` => `from systeminfo import SystemInfo`
  - `systeminfo.py`

The class I am trying to access in `client.py` is named `Client`.

## 3. The Error

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "..website\main.py", line 2, in 
  from client import Client

File "..website\client__init__.py", line 1, in 
  from client import Client

ImportError: cannot import name 'Client' from 'client' (..website\client__init__.py)

Can anyone have a look?

Answer (score 0):

In your main.py file you're importing the method Client from the directory *client*. What you want to do is import the method Client from the file *client* in the directory *client*.

```
from client.client import Client
```

Comment: OK thx, that did the trick.

Is there a reason why my Client class (client.py) does not recognize my Systeminfo class anymore (systeminfo.py)

client.py => from systeminfo import SystemInfo
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "..website\main.py", line 2, in from client.client import Client

File "..website\client\client.py", line 1, in from systeminfo import SystemInfo

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'systeminfo'